# Javascript | Why does the variable equal undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this code **largestGap** is equal to undefined when it is logged. Basically this code is turning the string of 1s and 0s into an array and finding the largest gap between two 1s, as you can see looking through largestGap should equal 4, but as stated earlier it returns undefined.

```js
var gaps = [];
var gapCount = 0;
var largestGap = gaps[0];
var string = '10010001000010001001';
string.split('');
var stringArray = Array.from(string);
stringArray.forEach(function(item, array) {
  if (item == '1') {
    if (gapCount > 0) {
      gaps.push(gapCount);
    }
    gapCount = 0;
  } else {
    gapCount++;
  }
});
for (i = 0; i < gaps.length; i++) {
  if (largestGap < gaps[i]) {
    largestGap = arr[i];
  }
}
console.log(`The largest gap in the string is ${largestGap}`);
```

Comment: `largestGap` is only defined if `largestGap < gaps[i])`. But since `largestGap` starts as `undefined`, this condition is never true.

Comment: At the very beginning `largestGap` is set equal to `gaps[0]`.

Comment: But `gaps[0]` is `undefined` at that point - you only just declared it (as the empty array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `largestGap` like:

```
var largestGap = gaps[0];
```

But the `gaps` array is empty initially. Initialize it only after the `gaps` array is populated, otherwise the test later (`if (largestGap < gaps[i])`) will not work.

There's also no `arr` variable. Use the `gaps` variable instead:

```js
var gaps = [];
var gapCount = 0;
var string = '10010001000010001001';
var stringArray = Array.from(string);
stringArray.forEach(function(item, array) {
  if (item == '1') {
    if (gapCount > 0) {
      gaps.push(gapCount);
    }
    gapCount = 0;
  } else {
    gapCount++;
  }
});
var largestGap = 0;
for (i = 0; i < gaps.length; i++) {
  if (largestGap < gaps[i]) {
    largestGap = gaps[i];
  }
}
console.log(`The largest gap in the string is ${largestGap}`);
```

Note that `string.split('');` does nothing - it creates an array, and that array is never used, so you can remove that line.

This could be done much more concisely by matching 0s with a regular expression, then mapping the array of matched substrings to each match's length, then calling `Math.max` with that array of lengths:

```js
const string = '10010001000010001001';
const matchLengths = (string.match(/0+/g) || []).map(str => str.length);
const largestGap = Math.max(...matchLengths);
console.log(`The largest gap in the string is ${largestGap}`);
```

The `|| []` is needed because, if there are no matches, the global regular expression match will return `null` rather than an empty array. If you're sure there will be at least one `0` in the string, you can remove that part to simplify things.

Comment: Ah I see, I wanted to declare all my variables at the top and didn't realize the error. Thanks for clearing that up! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are getting value from an empty array thats why first you should fill the gap array the use gap[0] insead of doing it before you even pushed anything to the array

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning variables as
`var gaps = [];`
`var gapCount = 0;`
`var largestGap = gaps[0];`

So `largestGap` in the end also will have no value as it is assigned at the beginning when `gaps` variable had no value